# How accurately does Google geocode UK postcodes using the maps api?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

If I provide a full UK postcode how much of it is taken into account? I remember reading that not all of it was used?

Answer (score 0):

From my basic tests I think that it is only the first part, plus first number of the second part. e.g. SW1A 0 that are used for geocoding. Adding any more (SW1A 0AA) makes no difference to the returned lat lng values.